# Swift: Indirect access / mutable

Tags: swift, pointers, mutable

I need to go to a referenced structure:

```
class SearchKnot {
    var isWord : Bool = false
    var text   : String = ""
    var toNext = Dictionary<String,SearchKnot>()    
}
```

When inserting, I need to update values in toNext dictionary. Because I want to avoid recursion, I do it in a loop. But there I need a variable which jumps from one toNext item to the other, able to change it.

```
var knots = toNext
...
let newKnot = SearchKnot()
knots[s] = newKnot
```

The last command only changes a local copy, but I need the original to be changed. I need an indirect access. In C I would use *p where I defined it as &toNext. But in Swift?

Comment: Please, can you show also the loop code?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I remembered old pascal days. ;-)
I don't use the last reference, but the second last. Instead of

```
knots[s]
```

I use

```
p.knots[s]
```

For hopping to the next knot, I also use

```
p = p.knots[s]
```

and could use

```
p.knots[s]
```

again. Also `p.knots[s] = newKnot` works, because p is local not the entire term.